# Generate MCQ from a text

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I need to know how to generate MCQ(Multiple Choice Question) questions from a text.

**Example:**

**Text-Input:** "Bangladesh (the People's Republic of Bangladesh) is a country in South Asia. It shares land borders with India and Myanmar (Burma)."

**Output:**

i) Where is in Bangladesh?

1. South Asia
2. Australia
3. Europe

b)Which country does share land border with India and Myanmar?

1. Thailand
2. Nepal
3. Bangladesh

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the complexity of your dataset. If its along the lines of your example then you can use simple POS tagging and cosine similarity.
But yeah essentially you'd have to use NLP.
Check out StanfordNER or spacy